# How to access a remote mongodb through Compass?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect to a mongodb database remotely.

I have the following information:

1. mongo DB on x.x.xxx.xxx
2. Username: tempUser
3. Password: tempPass
4. Host: localhost
5. port: 27017
6. needed port forwarding in order to access the DB as port 27017 is not open.

I've already tried to connect from console but I fail.

Is there a way to connect from Compass while I forward the port?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to connect to your instance from your workstation anywhere , ssh tunnelling is the way to go.

To use SSH Tunnel While creating a connection on MongoDB Compass , you need to choose it from the drop down box for the other text boxes to show up.
Image for post
The upcoming fields are pretty standard SSH information , nothing specific for MongoDB.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works, with one caveat: when SSH-tunneling to the server hosting MongoDB, remember to use `localhost` in the MongoDB connection string and hostname (on the first page of connection settings). Always use the perspective from the other end of the tunnel!

Answer (score -1):

If the port is open you can connect it with this command:

```
mongo --host ip -u user name -p password
```